# Dynamic Library Loading Issue: "Library not loaded" error when embedding Custom Framework within Another Custom Framework

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, linker-errors

[image]I am encountering a dyld error (`dyld[8942]: Library not loaded`) when attempting to embed `PaymentSampleFramework` within `POSSampleFramework`, and only linking `POSSampleFramework` in the main application. The error is as follows:

```
dyld[8942]: Library not loaded: @rpath/PaymentSampleFramework.framework/PaymentSampleFramework
Referenced from: <99DE58BE-5611-3397-BED2-6D7DDCE5A878> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B4CB8F71-F8A7-4A21-8C1B-170612C3C628/ParentApp.app/ParentApp
Reason: tried: '/usr/lib/swift/PaymentSampleFramework.framework/PaymentSampleFramework' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/PaymentSampleFramework.framework/PaymentSampleFramework' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B4CB8F71-F8A7-4A21-8C1B-170612C3C628/ParentApp.app/Frameworks/PaymentSampleFramework.framework/PaymentSampleFramework' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/PaymentSampleFramework.framework/PaymentSampleFramework' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/PaymentSampleFramework.framework/PaymentSampleFramework' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B4CB8F71-F8A7-4A21-8C1B-170612C3C628/ParentApp.app/Frameworks/PaymentSampleFramework.framework/PaymentSampleFramework'
```

The error occurs only when `PaymentSampleFramework` is not directly added to the application. I want to have only `POSSampleFrameWork` on the app side, with `PaymentSampleFramework` included within it.

I have shared the GitHub link to my workspace for reference: [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/sarathdev/MyWorkSpace) (Added PaymentSampleFramework inside application to avoid crash)

I'm seeking advice on whether it's possible to embed only `POSSampleFrameWork` without adding all internal dependencies. Any suggestions or solutions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why Apple discourages creating an umbrella framework, is the umbrella setup is the only solution!

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution is to make the internal libraries **static**. This would eliminate the need to include all internal dependencies on the application side.

**Are there any alternative solutions we should consider, and are there potential side effects to this approach?**